# Indirectly recursive - clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

What's the problem with following code:
the func expression get expression that contains term that can contain expression...

```
(defn term[]
    (def mytmp (zip/xml-zip {:tag :term}))
    (cond 
      (= (first(:content(first vecTok))) "(")
        (do
          (def mytmp (popVecTo mytmp))
          (def mytmp (zip/append-child mytmp (expression)))
          (def mytmp (popVecTo mytmp)))
      :else 
          (def mytmp (popVecTo mytmp)))
    (zip/node mytmp))
(defn expression[]
    (def mytmp (zip/xml-zip {:tag :expression}))
    (def mytmp (zip/append-child mytmp (term)))
    (while (contains? #{"+", "-", "*","/", "&", "|", "<", ">", "="} (first(:content(first vecTok))) )
      (do
        (def mytmp (popVecTo mytmp))
        (def mytmp (zip/append-child mytmp (term)))))
    (zip/node mytmp))
(def vecTok (vec (:content(first(xml-seq (parse  "C:/Users/User/Desktop/forHekronot/BallT.xml"))))))
```

In the file :

```
<a><symbol>(</symbol><identifier>dy</identifier><symbol>-</symbol><identifier>dx</identifier><symbol>)</symbol></a>
```

Comment: use def in defn is bad idea, please use let.

Comment: voted to close as no explanation of what the problem is that i can see.

Comment: Just a few issues that I see. 1) You're trying to write mutable code, instead of taking a more functional approach. 2) You're using `(def ...)` which define a top-level var instead of using something like [let](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/let) and the [threading macro](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E).  3) You appear to be constantly redefining `vecTok`, which isn't idiomatic Clojure.  I think what you need to do is backup, and look at the xml stream as a sequence, and operate on that sequence using `map`, `filter`, and other sequence abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding @jszakmeister's comment on how to better solve the problem, let me try to give and answer to the question:

you can first `(def expression)` and then `(defn term [] ...)` and finally `(defn expression [] ...)`.

The classic example for indirect recursion is of course the poor man's odd/even function for positive numbers:

```
clojurec.core=> (def even)
#'clojurec.core/even
clojurec.core=> (defn odd [x]  (and (not (= x 0)) (even (dec x))))
#'clojurec.core/odd
clojurec.core=> (defn even [x] (or (= x 0) (odd (dec x))))
#'clojurec.core/even
clojurec.core=> (even 10)
true 
clojurec.core=> (odd 10)
false
clojurec.core=> (odd 10000)
StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.Numbers.equal (Numbers.java:214)
```

Ooops, depending on the size (or rather depth) of your file this could be a problem. But not all is lost, we can redefine even to use `trampoline` internally:

```
(defn even [n] 
  (letfn [(evenrec [x] (or (= x 0) #(oddrec (dec x)))) 
          (oddrec  [x] (and (not (= x 0)) #(evenrec (dec x))))]
    (trampoline evenrec n)))
```